# Emacs permission issues

Tags: mu4e, email, permissions

I'm struggling trying to send email using mu4e. All is good using smtp but emacs does not want to go further as it stops saying it's impossible to create a directory (permission denied).
Here is the debug info

```
  signal(file-error ("Creating directory" "Permission non accordée" "/user-gmail"))
  files--ensure-directory("/user-gmail")
  make-directory("/user-gmail/[user].Drafts" t)
```

Actually the directory /user-gmail already exists. What am I missing?

About the permissions of this directory, I ran as suggested `ls -ld user-gmail/`
and got the following `drwxrwxr-x 9 guillaume guillaume 4096 déc.  28 15:52 user-gmail/`  (guillaume is my first name)

Comment: What are the permissions on that directory? You can find out by running `ls -ld /user-gmail` in a shell. If your system uses SELinux, add a `-Z` to that command. If you’re not using Linux, add that information to your question as well.

Comment: Is it user-gmail (at current directory) or /user-gmail (at filesystem tree root)?

Comment: @JeanPierre you're right, it is /user-gmail

Comment: So I guess that's the issue. It would be very "surprising" that user guillaume does have write permission in the root directory. You probably want to use /home/guillaume/user-gmail or something like that.